# python print statement displaying empty not giving exception

Tags: python

I am having some confusion about python's print statement and comment sign.

```
>>> print "Testing"
Testing
>>> print # "Testing"

>>> print#"Testing"

>>> print# #"Testing"

>>> print# ##"Testing"

>>> print# ###"Testing"

>>>
```

why i am not getting any error or exception when i am using # after print or  what is the reason behind display of  empty string.?

Comment: It's *not*  a function, it's a statement (at least in Python 2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything after `#` is a comment, and is ignored.

So,

```
print# ###"Testing"
```

is equivalent to:

```
print
```

From [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#an-informal-introduction-to-python):

> Comments in Python start with the hash character, `#`, and extend to the
>   end of the physical line. A comment may appear at the start of a line
>   or following whitespace or code, but not within a string literal. A
>   hash character within a string literal is just a hash character. Since
>   comments are to clarify code and are not interpreted by Python, they
>   may be omitted when typing in examples.

And you're using Python2, where `print` is still a statement not function.